Discover app does not start on Ubuntu Studio 24.04.1
Discover does not start,when I try to install updates the blinking icon shows but disappears in a short while and does not start,when I click on the discover icon happens the same thing;and I need Discover to install and remove programs.What can I do?

This is known bug and was announced in the release notes. I'm voting to close this question.

This is a known bug that was noted in the release notes:

An issue exists where Plasma Discover has a race condition when trying to load multiple backends and will not load properly. This may or may not happen and the issue is not 100% reproducible. If Discover does not launch for you, this is why.

There is currently no available fix. You will have to use an alternative package/software manager for now until this is fixed.
